# What's causing the submit button to be shifted downwards by some px?

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a very simple form consisting of an `<input type="text">` and an `<input type="submit">`.

Here is the HTML:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

form {
  background-color: #679;
  height: 3rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

input[type="text"] {
  height: 100%;
  width: 15rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  background-color: #eee;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #999;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
  <p>The form:</p>
  <form action="index.html">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..."><input type="submit">
  </form>
```

And here is the problem. This looks like this in all browsers that I tested:

[image]

The blue background is the `<form>`.

Why is the submit button shifted down and not in line with the text input element?

Furthermore, if the padding of the `<form>` element is removed, the submit button even sticks out of the `<form>` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `vertical-align: top` to your input element.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

form {
  background-color: #679;
  height: 3rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

input[type="text"] {
  height: 100%;
  width: 15rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  background-color: #eee;
  vertical-align: top;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #999;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<p>The form:</p>
<form action="index.html">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search..."><input type="submit">
</form>
```

In your example a flexbox would work even better, giving you a little bit more control and flexibility:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  
  background-color: #679;
  height: 3rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

input[type="text"] {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  background-color: #eee;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #999;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<p>The form:</p>
<form action="index.html">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search..."><input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Great, thanks! `vertical-align: top` and flexbox both solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

This is due to vertical alignement, you need to make it **top** or **bottom** to avoid the issue :

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  vertical-align:top;
}

form {
  background-color: #679;
  height: 3rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

input[type="text"] {
  height: 100%;
  width: 15rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  background-color: #eee;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #999;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p>The form:</p>
  <form action="index.html">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..."><input type="submit">
  </form>
```